# Bijection in the field of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functions, field-theory

Let $X$ be the set of tetrahedron's edges and $Y$ the set of its faces. To any function $f:X \to K$ for a field $K$, we assign a function $g:Y \to K$ defined as $g(Y)= \sum_{x\subset Y} f(x)$. That is, the value of $g$ on a face equals the sum of the values of $f$ on the sides of the face.
Let the above assignment be denoted as $\phi$: $F(X,K)-> F(Y,K),$
Show that, $\phi$ is surjective if K= $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of rational numbers.

**My thought**: I think this is  the bijection. First of all I would like to deal with the surjection part then I'll think about the injectivity. This is where I get stuck right now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that $F(X,K)$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension 6 and $F(Y,K)$ is a vector space of dimension 4.

Comment: How to show the bijection? Can you show the explicit map which works here

Comment: Number the faces $0, 1, 2, 3$. Denote the edges by the faces they lie between: $01, 02, 03, 12, 13, 23$. Then $$g(0) = f(01) + f(02) + f(03)\\g(1) = f(01) + f(12) + f(13)\\g(2) = f(02) + f(12) + f(23)\\g(3) = f(03) +f(13) + f(23)$$For the question of surjectivity, you choose an arbitrary $g$ and try to find an $f$ that matches. So the values of $g$ are known, and the values of $f$ are unknown. There are six unknowns and only four equations to satisfy.